# Is it possible to git grep for tabs?

Tags: git, grep

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825552/grep-a-tab-in-unix) specifies that `-P` allows GNU grep to grep for a tab

```
grep -P '\t' config/file.txt
```

However, using `git grep`, I can't work out how to grep for a tab:

```
git grep '\t' # Looks for files with the letter "t" instead
git grep -P '\t' # Invalid option
git grep -E '\t' # Does the same as without the -E
```

And there doesn't seem to be an option for substituting in your own `grep` program. Is my only option to slurp the entire contents and then use GNU grep on the results?

Comment: I wonder if `git grep '\\t'` would work.

Comment: For safe tab to space mass conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094383/how-can-i-convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-every-file-of-a-directory/52136507#52136507

Comment: `git grep -P` should work as long as your Git is compiled with libpcre (libpcre2 these days).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can work around this by typing a literal tab into your command:

```
# type it with ^V then tab
git grep '  '
```

Comment: :D well, yes. What's the Bash meaning of ctrl-v?

Comment: @three: That's not clear? Like I said, if you type ^V then tab, you get a literal tab. It interprets the next keystroke verbatim (literally), rather than giving it special interpretation.

Answer (score 40):

I cannot find a regexp notation for a tab that will work, but it will happily search for a literal tab if you can pass one in. In bash, that would be

```
git grep $'\t'
```

Comment: Such syntax also worked for grepping carriage returns: `git grep $'\r'`.

Comment: If you want need to do an even more specific search, such as using a regex to match the beginning of a line, then you can also do git grep '^'$'\t\t'

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, the following works in PowerShell:

```
git grep "`t"
```