# How can I convert tabs to spaces in every file of a directory?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, spaces, in-place

How can I convert tabs to spaces in every file of a directory (possibly recursively)?

Also, is there a way of setting the number of spaces per tab?

Comment: You want to replace tabs in files or filenames?

Comment: `pr` is a wonderful utility for this.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43774794/6862601).

Comment: Replacing tabs with spaces is not advised as it will harm others who work with the same files. Simply adjust the tools for the desired tab width instead.

Comment: `expand` and `unexpand` do the wonderful job.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> ### Warning: This will break your repo.
>
> This **will corrupt binary files**, including those under `svn`, `.git`! Read the comments before using!

`find . -iname '*.java' -type f -exec sed -i.orig 's/\t/    /g' {} +`

The original file is saved as `[filename].orig`.

Replace '*.java' with the file ending of the file type you are looking for. This way you can prevent accidental corruption of binary files.

Downsides:

- Will replace tabs everywhere in a file.
- Will take a long time if you happen to have a 5GB SQL dump in this directory.

Comment: for visual space that are a mix of tabs and spaces, this approach give incorrect expansion.

Comment: I would also add a file matcher like for example for only .php files          find ./ -iname "*.php" -type f -exec sed -i 's/\t/    /g' {} \;

Comment: DO NOT USE SED! If there's an embedded tab in a string, you may end up mangling your code. This is what [expand](http://man.cx/expand) command was meant to handle. Use `expand`.

Comment: @DavidW. I would simply update this command to only replace tabs from the beginning of the line. ```find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/^\t/####/g' {} \;```. But I wasn't aware of the expand command - very useful!

Comment: The answer's command just destroyed my local git repository. YMMV.

Comment: DO NOT USE! This answer also just wrecked my local git repository. If you have files containing mixed tabs and spaces it will insert sequences of #'s. Use the answer by Gene or the comment by Doge below instead.

Comment: I don't know why this would kill your local repository, it didn't do that for me. The `#` characters might need to be replaced by actual spaces, I assume that's what the "The # are spaces" in the answer meant. But the `^` does not help: you end up replacing just the first tab, subsequent tabs will not be replaced, i.e. useless!

Comment: Obviously, the amount of space that a tab expands to depends on the context. Thus, `sed` is a completely inappropriate tool for the task.

Comment: Yes, do not use. It messed up my files. Use the command from Gene.

Comment: See my answer below for a safer alternative. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41609013/1924979

Comment: -1 because (as @Sven pointed it out) it apparently disregards the tab size, which means this can only work correctly by *accidentally* matching the desired tab size, and will mess up the indentation (and any other sort of tabbed positioning) in every other case.

Comment: This is a pretty bad answer. It should probably be removed.

Comment: Jesus christ people, this answer has been edited into a complete incoherent mess. The warnings about it breaking the repo are now all false - they are left over from back when the answer's `find` command did not filter by file extension, and thus hit every file indiscriminately.

Answer (score 384):

Simple replacement with `sed` is okay but not the best possible solution.  If there are "extra" spaces between the tabs they will still be there after substitution, so the margins will be ragged.  Tabs expanded in the middle of lines will also not work correctly. In `bash`, we can say instead

```
find . -name '*.java' ! -type d -exec bash -c 'expand -t 4 "$0" > /tmp/e && mv /tmp/e "$0"' {} \;
```

to apply `expand` to every Java file in the current directory tree. Remove / replace the `-name` argument if you're targeting some other file types. As one of the comments mentions, be very careful when removing `-name` or using a weak, wildcard. You can easily clobber repository and other hidden files without intent. This is why the original answer included this:

> You should always make a backup copy of the tree before trying something like this in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Could someone explain why to use the _ in the command, rather than omit it and use $0?

Comment: @JeffreyMartinez Great question.  gniourf_gniourf edited my original answer on 11 November and made disparaging remarks about not knowing the proper way to use `{}`. Looks like he didn't know about `$0` when `-c` is used.  Then dimo414 changed from my use of a temp in the conversion directory to `/tmp`, which will be much slower if `/tmp` is on a different mount point.  Unfortunately I don't have a Linux box available to test your `$0` proposal.  But I think you are correct.

Comment: @Gene, thanks for the clarification, that sounds like stackoverflow alright :p . While I'm at it though, I'll add I had to use quotes around '*.java' for proper escaping of the *.java.

Comment: @JeffreyMartinez @Gene `Don't omit the _ and try to use $0 inside the mini-script -- not only would that be more confusing, but it is also prone to failure if the filename provided by find has special meaning as an argument to the shell.`   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Comment: The $0 positional parameter was really meant to expand to the name of the name of the programme if you leave out all arguments it actually expands to `bash` in that scenario.

Comment: @sabgenton But according to the bash documentation for the `-c` option: "If Bash is started with the -c option, then $0 is set to the first argument after the string to be executed, if one is present."  It seems they really meant to make the first argument available as `$0`.

Comment: It's obvious what the `-c` option allows but there's seems to be plenty of bash hackers that don't recommend using it that way in this context.  I'm no expert but I spose $1 will go blank if no args are given where as $0 will expand to 'bash' which is not what you want. gniourf_gniourf was not confused or anything, he was following the convention, I see no reason to challenge it.

Comment: @sabgenton, I don't follow what you mean by "...also prone to failure if the filename...has special meaning...to the shell".  I'm missing the part about how it would cause a problem whether we use the '_' or not. Could you clarify on that point? I get that this might be a "convention", but whenever I hear "convention" I'm weary that it might be code for "cause that's how everyone else does it" :p

Comment: @JeffreyMartinez The guy behind that website is heavily respected in the bash IRC community (more than anyone I've seen).  But I'm no expert and all I can tell you is $0 is across the board normally the name of the program.  Run `bash -c 'echo "$0"'` with out arguments and you will see 0 gives the name of the program 'bash' ,  if your argument returned nothing you will still get the string 'bash' in the program  why would you possibly want that?

Comment: You're right about $0 being 'bash' if I don't have an argument. But this is using 'find', which always supplies an argument (the filename), which, if there's an argument, gets assigned to $0, not 'bash'. Here is what I see, straight from  my terminal:
$ bash -c 'echo "|$0|$1|"' ----> |bash|| ...... 
$ bash -c 'echo "|$0|$1|"' one ----> 
|one|| .......
$ bash -c 'echo "|$0|$1|"' one two ------>
|one|two|

Comment: Furthermore, and I'll admit I searched for hardly 2 minutes, but I can't find where it's documented that 'bash' will show up in $0 when no arguments are passed in, whereas it's very clearly documented that you can expect the first argument after the string to appear in $0. I also disagree that '_' is more readable since unless you already know it's intention (because the guru told you once upon a time), it's impossible to determine what it's for.

Comment: Fair call though people get used to shell scripting using `./somefile  bla` and when using a file for scripting bla is "$1".  That's the norm :)

Comment: Warning for Windows users: [expand](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722332%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) means something entirely different.

Comment: If anybody is having a 'unknown primary or operator' error from find, then here is the full command which will fix it: `find . -name '*.java' ! -type d -exec bash -c 'expand -t 4 "$0" > /tmp/e && mv /tmp/e "$0"' {} \;`

Comment: @Micro  Thanks.  I made the original post that worked, but people keep editing it, breaking it in various ways.  Thanks for fixing it (again).

Comment: any idea how to do this on a windows machine using git-bash/msysgit ? Most Linux commands work for me. Getting "missing argument for '-exec'" on this one

Comment: @isimmons That's the setup I used to test it on Windows.  Works fine for me.  Is `bash` in your path? If not, you could try `\bin\bash` in place of `bash` in the command line.

Comment: @Gene yes bash is in the path. I can type bash and get bash-3.1$ But, I was using cmder. When I tried it with git-bash it works. Maybe when not run through git-bash it is trying to use the windows expand command or a problem with single vs double quotes. Don't know but it works in git-bash. Thanks

Comment: @isimmons As the post says, it's a bash command.  It will only make sense to a bash shell.

Comment: Was having issues again because of some changes to my system PATH which led me to find out in cmder I can type 'sh' which takes me into a shell prompt via msysgit/bin/sh.exe and then this command works perfectly. Better than having to go open git-bash to run it.

Comment: I thought this answer hadn't enough comments as it was, so this is mine: if use use `sponge` from https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/, you can write `find . -name '*.py' ! -type d -exec bash -c 'expand -t 8 "$0" | sponge "$0"' {} \;`

Comment: Don't be stupid and use `find . -name '*'`, I just destroyed my local git repo

Comment: Thank you, I used this for unexpand: find . -name "*.js" -exec bash -c 'unexpand -t 4 --first-only "$0" > /tmp/totabbuff && mv /tmp/totabbuff "$0"' {} \;

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: @Gene sorry for commenting here, but the answer you posted on my question was very good. I only edited the question because I was having trouble expressing precisely what I wanted, but your answer was definitely what I was looking for.

Comment: be advised: this will replace symlinks with the actual files.

Replace `! -type d` with `-type f` if you don't want this.

Comment: Worked for me with the following caveats; 1) On Mac had to use -type d @orestisf and 2) only worked with the name wildcard not in quotations.

Comment: This is my version: `find . -name '*.js' ! -type d -exec bash -c 'expand -t 2 "$0" > /tmp/e && mv /tmp/e "$0"' {} \;
`

Comment: I added `alias tabs_to_spaces="echo 'this-url'; echo \"find . -name '*.java' ! -type d -exec bash -c 'expand -t 4 "'\"\$0\"'" > /tmp/e && mv /tmp/e "'\"\$0\"'"' {} \\;\""` to remind me. It prints out the command to run C-c C-v style.

Comment: I often use this one to avoid hidden folders like `.git`: `find . -not -path '*/.git/*' -name '*.cs' -type f -exec bash -c 'expand -i -t 4 "$0" > /tmp/e && mv /tmp/e "$0"' {} \;`

Comment: This changes file permissions. I have fixed that with `chmod --reference`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52136507/895245

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 This doesn't change permissions. It creates new files with whatever default permissions (`umask`) usually set in `bashrc`.

Comment: @Gene yes, and therefore it sometimes changes file permissions, which is likely not what people want, notably for executable script files.

Comment: If that's a problem, you can change the final `mv` to `cp`. Of course you must have write permissions on the original file.

Comment: this doesn't work. the find command shows it is finding all of the files, but the expand command is only operating on like five of them, and i can't figure out why.. they're all `*.ts` files...

Comment: @ChaseMoskal Try giving the `expand`  and `mv` commands yourself on a file that wasn't transformed. Perhaps there's some permission or similar problem you'll be able to see. This has worked well for hundreds of people, so there must be something unique about your use case.

Answer (score 222):

Try the command line tool [`expand`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expand).

```
expand -i -t 4 input | sponge output
```

where

- `-i` is used to expand only leading tabs on each line;
- `-t 4` means that each tab will be converted to 4 whitespace chars (8 by default).
- [`sponge`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) is from the [`moreutils`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/utils/moreutils) package, and avoids [clearing the input file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33638511/1959808). On macOS, the package `moreutils` is available via [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/moreutils) (`brew install moreutils`) or [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/moreutils/) (`sudo port install moreutils`).

Finally, you can use `gexpand` on macOS, after installing `coreutils` with [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils) (`brew install coreutils`) or [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/coreutils/) (`sudo port install coreutils`).

Comment: It's one of [GNU_Core_Utilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities)

Comment: And for those systems that don't use the GNU Core Utilities, you have a decent chance of `expand` being installed since it is standardized by The Open Group's Single Unix Specification. See Issue 6, which is from 2001, though some updates were applied, hence the year of publication being 2004: [`expand`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/expand.html)

Comment: You should pass `-i` to `expand` to only replace leading tabs on each line. This helps avoids replacing tabs that might be part of code.

Comment: Can this be put inside a for loop? When I try that I get empty output files

Comment: how about for every single file in a directory recursively?

Comment: Every time I try to use this it blanks some (usually all) of the files. :\

Comment: @ThorSummoner: if `input` is the same file as `output` the bash clobbers the content before even starting `expand`. This is how `>` works.

Comment: @ThorSummoner You should look into `sponge`, which is useful for taking stdout and redirecting it back to the original file. It works by saving all the output coming to its stdin, waiting until the pipe is done, and only then opening and writing the original file. It is part of the `moreutils` package (often not installed by default).

Comment: Note: You're creating a new file and the new file might have different permissions as the file you started with.  I had some files with permission `0600`, after using `expand` the new file had the default permission of `0664`.  Using `sponge` and creating a new file had the same effect.  Using `sponge` and NOT creating a new file retained the original permissions.  Example: `expand --tabs=4 input | sponge input`.  Please note the use of `|` and not `>` in the `sponge` example.

Comment: expand -t 4 Foo | sponge Foo is the invocation I needed

Answer (score 47):

Collecting the best comments from [Gene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11094620/1147688), the best solution by far, is by using `sponge` from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).

```
sudo apt-get install moreutils
# The complete one-liner:
find ./ -iname '*.java' -type f -exec bash -c 'expand -t 4 "$0" | sponge "$0"' {} \;
```

**Explanation:**

- `./` is recursively searching from current directory
- `-iname` is a case insensitive match (for both `*.java` and `*.JAVA` likes)
- `type -f` finds only regular files (no directories, binaries or symlinks)
- `-exec bash -c` execute following commands in a subshell for each file name, `{}`
- `expand -t 4` expands all TABs to 4 spaces
- `sponge` soak up standard input (from `expand`) and write to a file (the same one)*.

**NOTE**: * A simple file redirection (`> "$0"`) won't work here because [it would overwrite the file too soon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29244408/1088580).

**Advantage**: All original file permissions are retained and no intermediate `tmp` files are used.

Answer (score 22):

Use backslash-escaped `sed`.

On linux:

- Replace all tabs with 1 hyphen inplace, in all *.txt files:

  ```
  sed -i $'s/\t/-/g' *.txt
  ```
- Replace all tabs with 1 space inplace, in all *.txt files:

  ```
  sed -i $'s/\t/ /g' *.txt
  ```
- Replace all tabs with 4 spaces inplace, in all *.txt files:

  ```
  sed -i $'s/\t/    /g' *.txt
  ```

On a mac:

- Replace all tabs with 4 spaces inplace, in all *.txt files:

  ```
  sed -i '' $'s/\t/    /g' *.txt
  ```

Comment: @Маша `sed -i '' $'s/\t/    /g' $(find . -name "*.txt")`

Comment: It breaks tabs that are part of the code.

Answer (score 10):

You can use  the generally available `pr` command (man page [here](https://ss64.com/bash/pr.html)).  For example, to convert tabs to four spaces, do this:

```
pr -t -e=4 file > file.expanded
```

- `-t` suppresses headers
- `-e=num` expands tabs to `num` spaces

To convert all files in a directory tree recursively, while skipping binary files:

```
#!/bin/bash
num=4
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for f in **/*; do
  [[ -f "$f" ]]   || continue # skip if not a regular file
  ! grep -qI "$f" && continue # skip binary files
  pr -t -e=$num "$f" > "$f.expanded.$$" && mv "$f.expanded.$$" "$f"
done
```

The logic for skipping binary files is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29689345/6862601).

**NOTE:**

1. Doing this could be dangerous in a git or svn repo
2. This is not the right solution if you have code files that have bare tabs embedded in string literals

Comment: Any advantage over `expand` given that both are POSIX? E.g. does it have an inline change option? Git safety at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52136507/895245

Answer (score 6):

My recommendation is to use:

```
find . -name '*.lua' -exec ex '+%s/\t/  /g' -cwq {} \;
```

*Comments:*

1. Use in place editing. Keep backups in a VCS. No need to produce *.orig files. It's good practice to diff the result against your last commit to make sure this worked as expected, in any case.
2. `sed` is a stream editor. Use `ex` for in place editing. This avoids creating extra temp files and spawning shells for each replacement as in the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094383/how-can-i-convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-every-file-of-a-directory/11094422#11094422).
3. WARNING: This messes with all tabs, not only those used for indentation. Also it does not do context aware replacement of tabs. This was sufficient for my use case. But might not be acceptable for you.
4. EDIT: An earlier version of this answer used `find|xargs` instead of `find -exec`. As pointed out by @gniourf-gniourf this leads to problems with spaces, quotes and control chars in file names cf. [Wheeler](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html).

Comment: `ex` might not be available on every Unix system. Substituting it with `vi -e` might work on more machines. Also, your regex replaces any number of starting tab characters with two spaces. Replace the regex with `+%s/\t/  /g` to no destroy multi level indentation. However this also affects tab characters that are not used for indentation.

Comment: ex is part of POSIX [1] so should be available.

Good point about multi level indendation. I had actually used the `/\t/  /` variant on my files, but opted for `/\t\+//` to not break non-indenting tabs. Missed the issues with multi-indentation! Updating the Answer.

[1] http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ex.1p.html#SEE%C2%A0ALSO

Comment: Using `xargs` in this way is useless, inefficient and broken (think of filenames containing spaces or quotes). Why don't you use `find`'s `-exec` switch instead?

Comment: I'd argue that filenames with spaces and quotes are broken ; )
If you need to support that I'd opt for: `-print0` options to find / xargs.
I like xargs over `-exec` since:
a) Separation of concerns
b) it can be swapped with GNU parallel more easily.

Comment: Updated adding @gniourf_gniourf comments.

Comment: Who said that filenames with spaces are broken? we're not on Windows, we're on Linux. A filename can be any valid non-empty C string that doesn't contain `/` (since I mentioned C string, the nil byte is of course forbidden). The robust, portable and efficient way is to use `-exec`: `find . -name '*.lua' -exec ex '+%s/\t/  /g' -cwq {} \;`. `xargs` should only be used in very very specific situations (that I yet have to discover).

Comment: Wheeler has elaborated the UNIX file name problem quite eloquently:
http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html
Allowing arbitraty C-strings was probably not the best design decision in the first place.
When I control the names, I try to avoid whitespace and control characters. But again, you clearly have a point. I added a comment to the answer: `-print0/-0` is also correct, and IMHO cleaner.

Comment: Thought about it again. Adopted -exec variant. Thx for the comments!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `find` with [`tabs-to-spaces`](https://github.com/stephenmathieson/tabs-to-spaces) package for this.

First, install `tabs-to-spaces`

```
npm install -g tabs-to-spaces
```

then, run this command from the root directory of your project;

```
find . -name '*' -exec t2s --spaces 2 {} \;
```

This will replace every `tab` character with 2 `spaces` in every file.

Answer (score 5):

I like the "find" example above for the recursive application. To adapt it to be non-recursive, only changing files in the current directory that match a wildcard, the shell glob expansion can be sufficient for small amounts of files:

```
ls *.java | awk '{print "expand -t 4 ", $0, " > /tmp/e; mv /tmp/e ", $0}' | sh -v
```

If you want it silent after you trust that it works, just drop the `-v` on the `sh` command at the end.

Of course you can pick any set of files in the first command. For example, list only a particular subdirectory (or directories) in a controlled manner like this:

```
ls mod/*/*.php | awk '{print "expand -t 4 ", $0, " > /tmp/e; mv /tmp/e ", $0}' | sh
```

Or in turn run find(1) with some combination of depth parameters etc:

```
find mod/ -name '*.php' -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 | awk '{print "expand -t 4 ", $0, " > /tmp/e; mv /tmp/e ", $0}' | sh
```

Comment: Shell globbing will break sooner or later, because the total amount of filenames can only be of `ARG_MAX` length. This is 128k on Linux systems, but I've encountered this limit enough times to not rely on shell globbing.

Comment: You don't really need to adapt them. `find` can be told `-maxdepth 1`, and it only processes the entries of the directory being modified, not the whole tree.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I convert tabs to spaces in every file of a directory (possibly
>   recursively)?

This is usually **not** what you want.

Do you want to do this for png images? PDF files? The .git directory? Your
`Makefile` (which *requires* tabs)? A 5GB SQL dump?

You could, in theory, pass a whole lot of exlude options to `find` or whatever
else you're using; but this is fragile, and will break as soon as you add other
binary files.

What you want, is at least:

1. Skip files over a certain size.
2. Detect if a file is binary by checking for the presence of a NULL byte.
3. Only replace tabs at the *start* of a file (`expand` does this, `sed`
   doesn't).

As far as I know, there is no "standard" Unix utility that can do this, and it's not very easy to do with a shell one-liner, so a script is needed.

A while ago I created a little script called
[sanitize_files](http://code.arp242.net/sanitize_files/) which does exactly
that. It also fixes some other common stuff like replacing `\r\n` with `\n`,
adding a trailing `\n`, etc.

You can find a simplified script *without* the extra features and command-line arguments below, but I
recommend you use the above script as it's more likely to receive bugfixes and
other updated than this post.

I would also like to point out, in response to some of the other answers here,
that using shell globbing is **not** a robust way of doing this, because sooner
or later you'll end up with more files than will fit in `ARG_MAX` (on modern
Linux systems it's 128k, which may seem a lot, but sooner or later it's *not*
enough).

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# http://code.arp242.net/sanitize_files
#

import os, re, sys


def is_binary(data):
    return data.find(b'\000') >= 0


def should_ignore(path):
    keep = [
        # VCS systems
        '.git/', '.hg/' '.svn/' 'CVS/',

        # These files have significant whitespace/tabs, and cannot be edited
        # safely
        # TODO: there are probably more of these files..
        'Makefile', 'BSDmakefile', 'GNUmakefile', 'Gemfile.lock'
    ]

    for k in keep:
        if '/%s' % k in path:
            return True
    return False


def run(files):
    indent_find = b'\t'
    indent_replace = b'    ' * indent_width

    for f in files:
        if should_ignore(f):
            print('Ignoring %s' % f)
            continue

        try:
            size = os.stat(f).st_size
        # Unresolvable symlink, just ignore those
        except FileNotFoundError as exc:
            print('%s is unresolvable, skipping (%s)' % (f, exc))
            continue

        if size == 0: continue
        if size > 1024 ** 2:
            print("Skipping `%s' because it's over 1MiB" % f)
            continue

        try:
            data = open(f, 'rb').read()
        except (OSError, PermissionError) as exc:
            print("Error: Unable to read `%s': %s" % (f, exc))
            continue

        if is_binary(data):
            print("Skipping `%s' because it looks binary" % f)
            continue

        data = data.split(b'\n')

        fixed_indent = False
        for i, line in enumerate(data):
            # Fix indentation
            repl_count = 0
            while line.startswith(indent_find):
                fixed_indent = True
                repl_count += 1
                line = line.replace(indent_find, b'', 1)

            if repl_count > 0:
                line = indent_replace * repl_count + line

        data = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, data))

        try:
            open(f, 'wb').write(b'\n'.join(data))
        except (OSError, PermissionError) as exc:
            print("Error: Unable to write to `%s': %s" % (f, exc))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    allfiles = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        for f in files:
            p = '%s/%s' % (root, f)
            if do_add:
                allfiles.append(p)

    run(allfiles)
```

Comment: Within git, the binary check is easy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52136507/895245

Answer (score 4):

I used [`astyle`](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) to re-indent all my C/C++ code after finding mixed tabs and spaces.  It also has options to force a particular brace style if you'd like.

Answer (score 4):

One can use `vim` for that:

```
find -type f \( -name '*.css' -o -name '*.html' -o -name '*.js' -o -name '*.php' \) -execdir vim -c retab -c wq {} \;
```

As Carpetsmoker stated, it will retab according to your `vim` settings. And modelines in the files, if any. Also, it will replace tabs not only at the beginning of the lines. Which is not what you generally want. E.g., you might have literals, containing tabs.

Comment: `:retab` will change all the tabs in a file, not those at the start. it also depends on what your `:tabstop` and `:expandtab` settings are in the vimrc or modeline, so this may not work at all.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Good point about tabs at the start of the lines. Does any of the solutions here handles this case? As for the `tabstop` and `expandtab` settings, it will work out if you're using `vim`. Unless you have mode lines in the files.

Comment: @x-yuri good question, but generally moot. Most people use \t not actual tabs in literals.

Answer (score 4):

To convert all Java files recursively in a directory to use 4 spaces instead of a tab:

```
find . -type f -name *.java -exec bash -c 'expand -t 4 {} > /tmp/stuff;mv /tmp/stuff {}' \;
```

Comment: How is this answer different from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11094620/1275169) which was posted 4 years ago?

Comment: So does your answer. In fact, this is an inferior version of Gene's answer: 1) Gene's answer take care of directories with same name. 2) It doesn't *move* if expand failed.

Answer (score 4):

**Git repository friendly method**

```
git-tab-to-space() (
  d="$(mktemp -d)"
  git grep --cached -Il '' | grep -E "${1:-.}" | \
    xargs -I'{}' bash -c '\
    f="${1}/f" \
    && expand -t 4 "$0" > "$f" && \
    chmod --reference="$0" "$f" && \
    mv "$f" "$0"' \
    '{}' "$d" \
  ;
  rmdir "$d"
)
```

Act on all files under the current directory:

```
git-tab-to-space
```

Act only on C or C++ files:

```
git-tab-to-space '\.(c|h)(|pp)$'
```

You likely want this notably because of those annoying Makefiles which require tabs.

The command `git grep --cached -Il ''`:

- lists only the tracked files, so nothing inside `.git`
- excludes directories, binary files (would be corrupted), and symlinks (would be converted to regular files)

as explained at: [How to list all text (non-binary) files in a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973057/how-to-list-all-text-non-binary-files-in-a-git-repository/24350112#24350112)

`chmod --reference` keeps the file permissions unchanged: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20645/clone-ownership-and-permissions-from-another-file Unfortunately I [can't find a succinct POSIX alternative](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20645/clone-ownership-and-permissions-from-another-file#comment849269_205583).

If your codebase had the crazy idea to allow functional raw tabs in strings, use:

```
expand -i
```

and then have fun going over all non start of line tabs one by one, which you can list with: [Is it possible to git grep for tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262150/is-it-possible-to-git-grep-for-tabs)

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 4):

No body mentioned `rpl`? Using rpl you can replace any string.
To convert tabs to spaces,

```
rpl -R -e "\t" "    "  .
```

very simple.

Comment: This corrupted all binary files in my repo.

Comment: An excellent command, but potentially dangerous with the recursive and all files in folder option as specified above.   I would add the --dry-run option "just in case" to make sure you are sitting in the right folder.

Answer (score 3):

Download and run the following script to recursively convert hard tabs to soft tabs in plain text files.

Execute the script from inside the folder which contains the plain text files.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -and -not -path './.git/*' -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -and -print | while read -r file; do {
    echo "Converting... "$file"";
    data=$(expand --initial -t 4 "$file");
    rm "$file";
    echo "$data" > "$file";
}; done;
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of `expand` as suggested in other answers seems the most logical approach for this task alone.

That said, it can also be done with Bash and Awk in case you may want to do some other modifications along with it.

If using Bash 4.0 or greater, the [shopt builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) `globstar` can be used to search recursively with `**`.

With GNU Awk version 4.1 or greater, sed like "inplace" file modifications can be made:

```
shopt -s globstar
gawk -i inplace '{gsub("\t","    ")}1' **/*.ext
```

In case you want to set the number of spaces per tab:

```
gawk -i inplace -v n=4 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=n;i++) c=c" "}{gsub("\t",c)}1' **/*.ext
```

Answer (score -1):

Converting tabs to space in just in ".lua" files [tabs -> 2 spaces]

```
find . -iname "*.lua" -exec sed -i "s#\t#  #g" '{}' \;
```

Comment: Obviously, the amount of space that a tab expands to depends on the context. Thus, sed is a completely inappropriate tool for the task.

Comment: ?? @Sven, my sed command does the same thing that expand command does (`expand -t 4 input >output`)

Comment: Of course not. `expand -t 4` will expand the tab in `a\tb` to 3 spaces and the tab in `aa\tb` to 2 spaces, just as it should be. `expand` takes the context of a tab into account, `sed` does not and will replace the tab with the amount of spaces your specify, regardless of the context.

Answer (score -1):

Use the vim-way:

```
$ ex +'bufdo retab' -cxa **/*.*
```

- <sup>**Make the backup!** before executing the above command, as it can corrupt your binary files.</sup>
- <sup>To use `globstar` (`**`) for recursion, activate by `shopt -s globstar`.</sup>
- <sup>To specify specific file type, use for example: `**/*.c`.</sup>

To modify tabstop, add `+'set ts=2'`.

However the down-side is that it can [replace tabs inside the strings](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/495/467).

So for slightly better solution (by using substitution), try:

```
$ ex -s +'bufdo %s/^\t\+/  /ge' -cxa **/*.*
```

Or by using `ex` editor + `expand` utility:

```
$ ex -s +'bufdo!%!expand -t2' -cxa **/*.*
```

For trailing spaces, see: [How to remove trailing whitespaces for multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711051/55075)

---

You may add the following function into your `.bash_profile`:

```
# Convert tabs to spaces.
# Usage: retab *.*
# See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11094383/55075
retab() {
  ex +'set ts=2' +'bufdo retab' -cxa $*
}
```

Comment: I downvoted many answers in this thread, not just yours ;-) Reasons are: [`:retab` may not work at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094383/how-can-i-convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-every-file-of-a-directory/31967701#comment51842782_26839565), [shell globbing is a bad solution for this sort of thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094383/how-can-i-convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-every-file-of-a-directory/31967701#comment51842591_23369021), your `:s` command will replace *any* amount of tabs with 2 spaces (which you almost never want), starting ex just to run an `:!expand` process is silly...

Comment: ...and all your solutions will clobber binary files and such (like .png files, .pdf files, etc.)

Comment: This is frankly a horrible suggestion for documentation - one has to be intimately acquainted with a number of fairly opaque syntax and semantic issues of several programs to be able to comprehend this.