# How to check if a file is binary?

Tags: shell, unix, binaryfiles

How can I know if a file is a binary file?

For example, a compiled C file is a binary file.

I want to read all files from some directory, but I want to ignore binary files.

Comment: Ultimately *all* files are binary. Text files just happen to contain binary representations of human-readable character data. No method for distinguishing text from non-text can be 100% reliable.

Comment: [Similar in Vim.](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3206/467)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use utility `file`, sample usage:

```
 $ file /bin/bash
 /bin/bash: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
 /bin/bash (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
 /bin/bash (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386

 $ file /etc/passwd
 /etc/passwd: ASCII English text

 $ file code.c
 code.c: ASCII c program text
```

[`file` manual page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file)

Comment: Consider using 'file --mine'. For binary files it reports "... charset=binary", so one can simply grep for the regexp "binary$".

Comment: @4dan - perhaps `--mime`? :)

Comment: @4dan Works for me: `file -bL --mime "$path" | grep -q '^text'`. Option `-b` removes the filename from the output, and `-L` dereferences symlinks.

Comment: 1. Does that work on non-x86 architectures? 2. do you consider a pdf file binary?

Comment: The answer should contain the `--mime` flag as it's otherwise not realistic to match output of `file` for all possible binary formats (such regex would be too long and fragile).

Comment: Prints a message if a file is a binary: `file -bL --mime "/my/file/path/some_binary" | grep -q "charset=binary" && echo "binary file"`. 

Answer (score 16):

Adapted from [excluding binary file](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/42573-search-files-excluding-binary-files.html)

```
find . -exec file {} \; | grep text | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: This should be `grep text`; historically, `file` didn't always say ASCII, but rather "shell script text" for example.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for reminding.  Just check `file` manpage, it should be `text`.

Comment: I just realized that reinvented the wheel once again:
for file in `find . -type f -exec file {} \; | grep text | perl -nle 'split /:/;print $_[0]' `; do grep -i --color 'string_to_search'  $file ; done ;

Comment: Thanks, used and adjusted it to find all binary files in a folder: `find . -type f -exec file {} \; | grep -v text | cut -d: -f1`

Comment: and what if the filename contains the word "text"? I use grep ".*:.*text" now

Comment: If (like me) you find the `\;` especially ugly, note that in many cases `+` (POSIX-compatible) will do as well:  `find ... -exec foo {} +` is similar to `find ... | xargs foo`.

Comment: @Algoman I use `file -b`, which doesn't output the filename. (Might be a GNU-only feature).

Comment: Not 100% reliable. A json file is reported as `JSON data`. I'm sure there are other exceptions. Also, I just checked, and `-b` works on a Mac as well.

Comment: Honestly, at this point it would be easier to write a tiny utility and put it in your path.

Answer (score 16):

I use

```
! grep -qI . "$path"
```

Only drawback I can see is that it will consider an empty file binary but then again, who decides if that is wrong?

EDIT based on [@mgutt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318765/mgutt)'s suggestion:

In some contexts the file could be huge so depending on what you need to do it might be safer and sufficient to read only part of the file:

```
head -c 1024 "$path" | grep -qI .
```

Keep in mind though, that you will need to choose the size wisely; 1024 bytes of text plus a null byte is still a binary file.

Comment: The empty file case can be controlled by adding `|| ! test -s $path`.

Comment: Grep for empty string (`''`), not for any single character (`'.'`): **`! fgrep -qI '' "$path"`**. In that way empty files and files consisting only of new-line markers (line feeds) will be treated as textual.

Comment: @yugr, that wouldn't really help, because the original Alois Mahdal's code will treat not only absolutely empty files (zero size) as binary, but also files consisting of one or more linefeeds. But that could be easily fixed (see my comment above), Alois Mahdal's idea is great.

Comment: Note: This will read the whole file if it is a text file, for example a 1GB log file will be fully processed. Maybe its better to check only the first 1024 bytes with `head -c 1024 "$path" | grep -qIF ''`?!

Comment: @mgutt Nice, although the curse of format detection will still rear its ugly head: *technically* a 10GB of ASCII and one null byte is still a binary file, so figuring out the offset would be essential and context dependent...

Answer (score 5):

#### [BSD `grep`](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep)

Here is a simple solution to check for a single file using [BSD `grep`](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep) (on macOS/Unix):

```
grep -q "\x00" file && echo Binary || echo Text
```

which basically checks if file consist NUL character.

Using this method, to read all non-binary files recursively using `find` utility you can do:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -q "\x00" {} || cat {}' ";"
```

Or even simpler using just `grep`:

```
grep -rv "\x00" .
```

For just current folder, use:

```
grep -v "\x00" *
```

Unfortunately the above examples won't work for [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/), however there is a workaround.

#### [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/)

Since GNU `grep` is ignoring NULL characters, it's possible to [check for other non-ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001177/55075) like:

```
$ grep -P "[^\x00-\x7F]" file && echo Binary || echo Text
```

<sup>Note: It won't work for files containing only NULL characters.</sup>

Comment: What version of `grep` is that? With GNU grep 3.1, searching for `\x00` always fails.

Comment: I'm using BSD grep on macOS, it seems it works on it, not on the GNU one.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev I've [added more universal method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49806047/55075) which works for both `grep` versions, please check.

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -E 'exit((-B $ARGV[0])?0:1);' file-to-test
```

Could be used to check whenever "file-to-test" is binary. The above command will exit wit code 0 on binary files, otherwise the exit code would be 1.

The reverse check for text file can look like the following command:

```
perl -E 'exit((-T $ARGV[0])?0:1);' file-to-test
```

Likewise the above command will exit with status 0 if the "file-to-test" is text (not binary).

Read more about the `-B` and `-T` checks using command `perldoc -f -X`.

Answer (score 3):

Use Perl’s built-in `-T` file test operator, preferably after ascertaining that it is a plain file using the `-f` file test operator:

```
$ perl -le 'for (@ARGV) { print if -f && -T }' \
    getwinsz.c a.out /etc/termcap /bin /bin/cat \
    /dev/tty /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/motd
getwinsz.c
/etc/termcap
/etc/motd
```

Here’s the complement of that set:

```
$ perl -le 'for (@ARGV) { print unless -f && -T }' \
    getwinsz.c a.out /etc/termcap /bin /bin/cat \
    /dev/tty /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/motd
a.out
/bin
/bin/cat
/dev/tty
/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC
```

Answer (score 3):

Going off [Bach's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16760378/113632#comment37557116_16760396), I think `--mime-encoding` is the best flag to get something reliable from [`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file).

```
file --mime-encoding [FILES ...] | grep -v '\bbinary$'
```

will print the files that `file` believes have a non-binary encoding. You can pipe this output through `cut -d: -f1` to trim the `:   encoding` if you just want the filenames.

---

Caveat: as @yugr reports below `.doc` files report an encoding of `application/mswordbinary`. This looks to me like a bug - the mime type is erroneously being concatenated with the encoding.

```
$ for flag in --mime --mime-type --mime-encoding; do
    echo "$flag"
    file "$flag" /tmp/example.{doc{,x},png,txt}
  done
--mime
/tmp/example.doc:  application/msword; charset=binary
/tmp/example.docx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=binary
/tmp/example.png:  image/png; charset=binary
/tmp/example.txt:  text/plain; charset=us-ascii
--mime-type
/tmp/example.doc:  application/msword
/tmp/example.docx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
/tmp/example.png:  image/png
/tmp/example.txt:  text/plain
--mime-encoding
/tmp/example.doc:  application/mswordbinary
/tmp/example.docx: binary
/tmp/example.png:  binary
/tmp/example.txt:  us-ascii
```

Comment: Plain `--mime` does works though (`application/msword; charset=binary`).

Comment: @yugr that's interesting - it almost looks like a bug in `file`, since a `.docx` file prints `binary` for `--mime-encoding`.

Comment: Forgot to report back here, but the [`.doc` bug was fixed](https://bugs.astron.com/view.php?id=18).

Answer (score 3):

#### `cat`+`grep`

Assuming binary means the file containing NULL characters, this shell command can help:

```
(cat -v file.bin | grep -q "\^@") && echo Binary || echo Text
```

or:

```
grep -q "\^@" <(cat -v file.bin) && echo Binary
```

This is the workaround for [`grep -q "\x00"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30133802/55075), which works for BSD grep, but not for GNU version.

Basically `-v` for `cat` converts all non-printing characters so they are visible in form of control characters, for example:

```
$ printf "\x00\x00" | hexdump -C
00000000  00 00                                             |..|
$ printf "\x00\x00" | cat -v
^@^@
$ printf "\x00\x00" | cat -v | hexdump -C
00000000  5e 40 5e 40                                       |^@^@|
```

where `^@` characters represent NULL character. So once these control characters are found, we assume the file is binary.

---

The disadvantage of above method is that it could generate false positives when characters are not representing control characters. For example:

```
$ printf "\x00\x00^@^@" | cat -v | hexdump -C
00000000  5e 40 5e 40 5e 40 5e 40                           |^@^@^@^@|
```

See also: [How do I grep for all non-ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001177/55075).

Comment: That produces a false "Binary" result with a text file containing the three ASCII characters `\^@`.

Comment: Added a note, check also: [How do I grep for all non-ASCII characters in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001177/55075).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command-line:

```
file "$FILE" | grep -vq 'ASCII' && echo "$FILE is binary"
```

Comment: Nice but is fooled by urt8 ascii file. I used:  file "$FILE" | grep -vq 'text'

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of brute force to exclude binary files with `tr -d "[[:print:]\n\t]" < file | wc -c`, but it is no heuristic guesswork either.

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec /bin/sh -c '
   for file in "$@"; do
      if [ $(LC_ALL=C LANG=C tr -d "[[:print:]\n\t]" < "$file" | wc -c) -gt 0 ]; then
         echo "${file} is no ASCII text file (UNIX)"
      else
         echo "${file} is ASCII text file (UNIX)"
      fi
   done
' _ '{}' +
```

The following brute-force approach using `grep -a -m 1 $'[^[:print:]\t]' file` seems quite a bit faster, though.

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec /bin/sh -c '
   tab="$(printf "\t")"
   for file in "$@"; do
      if LC_ALL=C LANG=C grep -a -m 1 "[^[:print:]${tab}]" "$file" 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
         echo "${file} is no ASCII text file (UNIX)"
      else
         echo "${file} is ASCII text file (UNIX)"
      fi
   done
' _ '{}' +
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also by leveraging the `diff` command. Check this answer:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275516/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-classify-files-as-binary-or-text#answer-402870

Answer (score 0):

#### `grep`

Assuming binary means file containing non-printable characters (excluding blank characters such as spaces, tabs or new line characters), this may work (both BSD and GNU):

```
$ grep '[^[:print:][:blank:]]' file && echo Binary || echo Text
```

<sup>Note: [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) will report file containing only NULL characters as text, but it would work correctly on [BSD version](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep).</sup>

<sup>For more examples, see: [How do I grep for all non-ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001177/55075).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would suffice ..

```
if ! file /path/to/file | grep -iq ASCII ; then
    echo "Binary"
fi

if file /path/to/file | grep -iq ASCII ; then
    echo "Text file"
fi
```