# How do I open a program in bash that I do not know the path to

Tags: bash

The problem is that which is not storing the path to the program.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter progam name: " name
path=which $name
nano $path
```

Comment: i just like to look at them.

Comment: @janos `Which` works on any executable, not just binary. @MreeM, you can use `$()` around your `which $name` bit,  like `path=$(which $name)` You should also quote your $path variable in case it has spaces: `nano "$path"`  You could also just use `nano "$(which $name)"`

Comment: @janos I've updated my comment/answer to remove the backtick suggestion. Hard to show an example of those within a codeblock here in a comment anywa.

Comment: `which` will just look for files in `$PATH`, if the file you want to know the path is not in any directory set in your `$PATH`, `which` will not help you. You can use find to search for it, but search for it in you entire disk will take a long time, you should have at least some base path to search it.

Comment: `nano "$(which "$name")"`, rather, if you want to be able to refer to names with spaces. And better not to rely on `which`, which is nonstandard -- the POSIX-compliant alternative is `command -v`.

Comment: BTW, `path=which $name` is running `$name` as a command with the environment variable `path` set to the value `which`. It **does not** run `which`.

Answer (score 2):

```
path=which $name
```

This isn't the syntax you need. This invokes a command stored in `$name` with a variable `path=which` added to its environment. If you'd quoted it, as in `path="which $name"` you'd instead set `path` in your environment, but it would contain the string `which ...` (where ... is the value of `$name`).

What you're looking for is [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), which allows you to capture the output of a command. So instead you should do:

```
path="$(which "$name")"
```

This will set `path` to the result of `which "$name"`, which is what you want.

As suggested in the comments you can skip the `path` variable entirely and just say:

```
nano "$(which "$name")"
```

You can even skip this script entirely assuming you don't mind remembering the syntax, and just entering:

```
$ nano "$(which command-to-look-at)"
```

Directly in the prompt.

---

Going the other way, if you want something more robust you can avoid opening [binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45177322/113632) with something like this (notice it's a function rather than a script, you can add it to your `.bashrc` directly or pull out the body into a separate script if you prefer):

```
inspect_command() {
  local name="${1:?No command provided}"
  local path
  path=$(which "$name") || {
    echo "No command '$name' found"  
    return 1
  }
  if [[ "$(file --brief --mime-encoding "$path")" == "binary" ]]; then
    echo "$path appears to be a binary file."
    local response;
    read -p "Are you sure you'd like to continue? [y/N] " response;
    [[ "$response" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]] || return 0
  fi
  "${EDITOR:-nano}" "$path"
}
```

This behaves the same as above on text files (though you pass the command as an argument, and it uses your preferred `EDITOR` if one is set), but warns you before attempting to open binary files.

```
$ inspect_command curl
/usr/bin/curl appears to be a binary file.
Are you sure you'd like to continue? [y/N] n

$ inspect_command some_script.sh
... opens nano
```

Comment: What is the meaning to run something like this: `nano "$(which curl)"`? It is a binary file. So I believe it is trying to open (edit with `nano`) a normal file, a text file, and a normal file probably will not be in the `PATH`. `which` can be used to get the path for a normal file also, but in this case it needs to update the `PATH` and this is exactly what is not know.

Comment: Right, it's not always a meaningful thing to do. There are many programs that *aren't* binaries, and which can be interesting to inspect. As OP noted above "*i just like to look at them*".

Comment: @Azize I've added an extended function that handles binary commands gracefully. There are many commands on the average `PATH` that are actually scripts; I bet you'll find more than you expect if you look.

Answer (score -1):

Use `find` instead of `which`.

`path=$(find /some/base/path -type f -name "${name}")`

Comment: The OP is explicitly asking only for the names of programs. Searching only through the PATH is appropriate, and much faster, in this case.

Comment: Please elaborate your explanation, it is clear for me what you are saying.

Comment: The OP's intent is to locate a program on the `PATH` (hence they're using `which`) and then open it. They can't use `find` since they aren't looking in a fixed `/some/base/path`.

Comment: But where in the question It says it is looking for files in PATH?

Comment: That's what `which` does - it looks for matching files on the `PATH`.

Comment: @Azize, that's the reasonable inference from the phrase "open a program", and the OP's attempt to use `which` (which would have worked if they got their syntax right).

Comment: I know that, but that is exactly the problem, let me quote the question: "The problem is that which is not storing the path to the program". It is not storing the path because usage of `which` is wrong, as stated before, or because the file is not in the PATH at all.