# How to find out human unreadable file in the directory?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a source code which is having text and binary file. I have to find and collect all the human unreadable files present in source code. How I can do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760378/how-to-check-if-the-file-is-a-binary-file-and-read-all-the-files-which-are-not

Comment: I have tried this grep -q ASCII $name && echo $name Binary || echo $name Text .
but all png files displaying as a text file.                                                                    o/p:wear-round-4.png Text
      mobile-1-list.png Text
      wear-round-3.png Text
      menu.png Text
      main.png Text
      main.png Text

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code returns a list of all non ascii text files in current directory.
Hope this will help:

```
for i in `find . -type f`; do file $i; done |grep -v text | cut -d : -f 1
```

You could replace the `.` (dot) after the `find` with any other location in your filsystem.

Comment: Maybe remove `ASCII` so it filters out other text encodings like UTF-8 as well: `$ echo 'hellö wørld' | file -` gives `/dev/stdin: UTF-8 Unicode text`.

Comment: Instead of two unquoted expansions, you could do `find . -type f -exec file {} \;` | grep ...`

Comment: That's right Benjamin. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer of Far Had is correct, you don't even need a for-loop for this. As you state yourself, all your files are within one directory, so you can simply run:

```
file *
```

The answers containing "text" (be it ASCII, unicode or something else) indicate human readable files.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use perl (File::Find module) like this:

```
perl -MFile::Find -e '@directories=shift || "."; sub wanted { ! -T && print "$File::Find::name\n"; }; find(\&wanted,  @directories);'
```

NOTE: The above command defaults to searching the current directory.
To search a specific directory e.g. /tmp, just type the above command followed by a space and /tmp