# How to list all text (non-binary) files in a git repository?

Tags: git, text-files

I have a repository with a lot of autogenerated source files I've marked as "binary" in `.gitattributes` (they are checked in because not everyone has access to the generator tools). Additionally, the repo has a lot of source-ish files in ignored directories (again, generated as part of the build processes), and a number of actual binary files (e.g. little resource files like icons).

I'd now like to find all the non-auto-generated and non-ignored files in the repo. I thought I'd just do this with `find` and a bunch of exclusions, but now I have a horrendous `find` statement with a dozen clauses (and it still doesn't perfectly do the job). `git ls-files` works but shows me all the binary files without differentiation, which I have to filter out.

So, I'm wondering: is there a simple command I can run which lists every file checked into the the repo, and which `git` considers a "text" file?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
git grep --cached -Il ''
```

lists all non-empty regular (no symlinks) text files:

- `-I`: don't match the pattern in binary files
- `-l`: only show the matching file names, not matching lines
- `''`: the empty string makes `git grep` match any non-empty file
- `--cached`: also find files added with `git add` but not yet committed (optional)

Or you could use [How to determine if Git handles a file as binary or as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119956/how-to-determine-if-git-handles-a-file-as-binary-or-as-text) in a for loop with `git ls-files`.

TODO empty files.

Find all binary files instead: [Find all binary files in git HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689384/find-all-binary-files-in-git-head/32267369#32267369)

Tested on Git 2.16.1 with [this test repo](https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-file-types/tree/f82d2d477a552d5fd8dab521f78a79390eb8927e).

Comment: And for piping into `xargs -0` there's the option `-z`.

Answer (score 4):

A clever hack to achieve this: listing all non-binary files that contains carriage returns

```
$ git grep --cached -I -l -e $'\r'
```

For my case, an empty string works better:

```
$ git grep --cached -I -l -e $''
```

Took it from [git list binary and/or non-binary files?](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-list-binary-and-or-non-binary-files-td3506370.html).

Comment: No need for `$` in `$''`, `''` is more portable.

Answer (score 3):

You use gits `eol` attributes to find non-binary files.

```
git ls-files --eol | grep 'i/lf'
```

This list all files that are checked in having 'LF' line-endings.

This has the advantage of using the `git ls-files` command, so it can easily be piped to `xargs`. It's also a plumbing command, so it might be faster (I haven't benchmarked).

This may be a viable alternative to using the [`git grep` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24350112/1507124) as it appears to be more customizable in terms of what one considers *binary* and not.

Note that you can specify which files git should consider *binary* in `.gitattributes`. So if you add `*.svg binary` to `.gitattributes`. The `git grep` method respects this. The `eol` attribute will also respect, but not for old files already checked into the index prior to setting the attribute. But you can always add a `| grep -v 'attr/-text'` to exclude files that have been set as binary in the `.gitattributes`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method for listing non-ignored files is:

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard --cached
```

But, as you seen, it lists *all* versioned files.

One workaround could be to define in a separate file "`exclude_binaries`" an [**exclusion pattern**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#_exclude_patterns) in order to match all binaries that you know of.

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard --cached \
--exclude-from=/path/to/`exclude_binaries`
```

That would be a less complex `find`, but it doesn't provide a fully automated way to list non-binary files: you still have to identify and list them in a separate pattern file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `git ls-files` and `awk`:

```
git ls-files --eol | awk -F '\t' '{if ($0 !~ /^i\/-text/) print $2}'
```

Note: this solution also works and returns non-binary, empty files.

Explanation:

- `--eol`: show `<eolinfo>` and `<eolattr>` of files. Ref.: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt---eol
- `awk -F '\t'`: parse and separate the piped input lines by tabs. At least with git version 2.37.2, the output format of `git ls-files --eol` displays 4 "humanly-readable" columns, however, only the last 4th is preceded by tab. Accordingly, if we separate by tabs, `awk` considers two columns.
- (awk) `if ($0 !~ /^i\/-text/)`: only match if the line does not start with `i/-text/`. This is our test to know that the file is NOT a binary file.
- (awk) `print $2`: print the 2nd column, which is the file's path (as requested by the OP). Note that this solution also works for filenames containing spaces.

*Acknowledgment*: My answer expands on @CervEd answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67346778/341320) and also takes as a reference another post answer from @Quential33 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66796286/341320)