# How to list all files tracked by Git excluding submodules?

Tags: git, bash

```
git ls-files
```

also lists submodules.

With: [List submodules in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641469/list-submodules-in-a-git-repository) and [How to remove the lines which appear on file B from another file A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file) I can do:

```
git ls-files | grep -Fxvf <(git submodule status | cut -d' ' -f3)
```

or the more verbose and versatile:

```
git ls-files | while IFS='' read -r file; do
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
```

Is there a shorter way using some git command / flags?

Comment: Probably not, since those submodules have tree entries in your parent git repository.  It seems entirely reasonable that they are displayed by `git ls-files`.  I encourage you to consider implement a `--no-submodules` flag for `git ls-files` and submitting the patch to `git`; they might just take it.

Answer (score 9):

```
git grep --cached -l ''
```

lists all non-empty files, excluding both submodules and symlinks.

You may also be interested in excluding binary files for your mass refactorings: [How to list all text (non-binary) files in a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973057/how-to-list-all-text-non-binary-files-in-a-git-repository/24350112#24350112)

Tested on Git 2.16.1 with [this test repo](https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-file-types/tree/f82d2d477a552d5fd8dab521f78a79390eb8927e).

Answer (score 4):

`git ls-files` has a `-s` option to list staged files' mode bits and other status indicators straight from the index, you can test those

```
git ls-files -s | grep -v ^16 | cut -f2-
```

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend parsing the `.gitmodules` file directly is generally safer and much faster than `git submodule status`.  This file can be parsed using `git config` to ensure that all parsing edge cases are handled appropriately -- formatting, whitespace, comments, etc:

```
git ls-files | grep -Fxvf  <(git config --file .gitmodules --name-only --get-regexp path | cut -d '.' -f2-)
```

Alternatively, the file can be parsed directly so long as the regex is designed so that it won't match submodules which have been commended out via `#`:

```
git ls-files | grep -Fxvf  <(grep "^\s*\[submodule " .gitmodules | cut -d '"' -f2)
```

---

Note that `git submodule status` has an output format that makes it difficult to correctly to parse via `cut`.  The two main drawbacks are:

- the field of the filename will change depending on if the module is initialized or not
- the filename is not delimited by tab `\t`, and it isn't the last thing on the line, so filenames with spaces cannot be handled correctly.