# git ensure newline at end of each file

Tags: git, newline

`git` doesn't like files that don't end with a newline (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813311/no-newline-at-end-of-file/44641937) for example). Suppose I want to clean up my repository and make sure each file ends properly with a newline (without adding useless newlines), is there some kind of tool or command that could help me do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for f in $(git grep --cached -Il ''); do tail -c1 $f | read -r _ || echo >> $f; done
```

**explanation**

- `git grep --cached -Il ''` lists all **text** files in the git index ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973057/how-to-list-all-text-non-binary-files-in-a-git-repository))
- `tail -c1` reads the last character
- `read` builtin exits nonzero if it detects `EOF` before it finds a `\n`
- `echo >> $f` is only executed when the read command fails

ps: inspired by https://backreference.org/2010/05/23/sanitizing-files-with-no-trailing-newline/

Comment: Will this break binary files?

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon very good remark. I changed the script to affect only text files.