# override all default clang-format settings except UseTab and IndentWidth

Tags: clang-format

I want to convert all tabs to (4)spaces in my code. Clang-format does this, but re-formats everything else, probably using the default settings. Is there any way I could disable all of these default settings and just use the IndentWidth and UseTab setting?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to swat flies with a sledgehammer here. Your ide should be able to do this for new files. To apply this change to a bunch of files, use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094383/how-can-i-convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-every-file-of-a-directory) or the equivalent tools in your command-line environment.