# Is there a way to change all tabs to spaces for all files in a directory using bash?

Tags: bash, tabs, spaces

I have just inherited a new C++ project where plenty of files are indented with tabs while more recent ones are programmed with spaces. Now I want to change them all to using spaces only. Instead of going into every files and using EMacs auto-indent function, is there a more efficient way I could achieve it with bash?

Comment: OFC there is (are); e.g you could write a _for each_ + `sed` script...What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are the files all in one directory or in multiple subdirectories?

Comment: @cyrus the files are in multiple directories/subdirectories

Comment: @danlor I was reserved about using `sed` due to the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094383/how-can-i-convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-every-file-of-a-directory)

Comment: What didn't work?

Comment: Then you can use `expand` or other similar tools. However, you can just filter the target files (only *.cpp) before piping them to `sed` in order to avoid making a huge mess of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert tabs to spaces in every file of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094383/how-can-i-convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-every-file-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 3):

This will traverse the project files recursively and expand the tabs to spaces. Since I'm sure you're using source control, you can easily revert if something goes awry.

```
find /path/to/project -type f -name '*.cpp' -exec expand --initial {} +
```

The default is eight spaces, but you can use `--tabs=4` or whatever value you want.

The `--initial` option ignores tabs which follow non blanks.

Comment: Very nice. And `unexpand` to convert spaces to tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I have two answers.  First, to answer your specific question, I'd use `perl` or similar, like so:

**replace-tab-indents.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while ($line = <STDIN>) {
    while ($line =~ /^ *\t/) {
        $line =~ s/^( *)\t/$1    /;
    }

    print(STDOUT $line);
}
```

This deals with *only TABs at the start of the line*.  This is crucial to your use case, because you don't want to replace other TABs; e.g., those that are part of some static string in the code.

Use this inside of a shell script such as:

```
for FILE in `find . -name *.cpp`; do
    mv -i "$FILE" "$FILE.bak"
    cat "$FILE.bak" | replace-tab-indents.pl > "$FILE"
done
```

The use of the `-name` option on `find` limits you to just your source files, avoiding the problems that you correctly are wary of related to replacing all TABs in all files -- in many non-source files, the "TAB" byte is crucial to the data that comprises that file.

**My second answer is to just change them as you go, instead of all at once.**

This way you can employ emacs (or vim, or any modern editor, really), which will be a more tested, tried-and-true, robust approach.

The files compile just fine with TABs, so until you need to edit a given file, the presence of the TAB indentation does not affect you; at exactly the point in time when it affects you (i.e., the first time you edit it), you can use your editor to re-indent with spaces.  In short, my advice here is to accomplish this just-in-time / as-you-go, not all-at-once.

Said differently, the compiler doesn't care about the indentation, only you do; and the only time you will care is when you actually edit a given source file; so, there is no empirical benefit from re-indenting your source files *en mass*.

Answer (score 1):

Using any solution using `find` one has to think about all possible filename extensions, looking at the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) there are plenty of them.

[Ack](https://beyondgrep.com/) has a very good file selection option, just pass `--cc` as parameter to only match C++ files.

So, replace all tabs in all C++ files including header files use:

```
ack --cpp -l --print0 . | xargs -0 -n1 sed -i -e 's/\t/    /'
```

`ack` will find all C++ files recursively in the current directory and pass only the file names to `sed`, which replaces all tabs with four spaces.