# How do you search for tab characters in Git commits?

Tags: git, git-log

When searching for a regular string in Git commits, you can use this command:

```
git log -S'string'
```

But searching for a tab character doesn't work:

```
git log -S'\t'
```

I've also tried using `--pickaxe-regex` and `--perl-regexp` with variations of tab representations with no luck.

How do you express a tab character so it can be found?

Comment: Have you tried actually typing a tab? If you're on a Unix shell and it triggers command completion, type control-V then tab.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4262150/2541573

Comment: I tried pasting a tab from the clipboard, but this doesn't work of course. Typing a tab the way you mentioned worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bash you can do

```
git log -S"$(echo -e '\t')"
```

or type a tab by pressing CTRL+V, then TAB.

Comment: You can replace `"$(echo -e '\t')"` with `"$'\t'"`, it's a bit shorter (i am, however,  not sure how portable it is).