# Search for tabs, without -P, using 'grep'

Tags: regex, grep

I used to use `grep -P` successfully earlier, till I got a machine where grep is not compiled with Perl regular expression support. Now I am having trouble matching tabs:  `\t` character,

```
grep -G '\t' matches a literal 't'
grep -E '\t' matches a literal 't'
```

How do I match tabs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
grep -G $'\t'
```

For more info please see [bug #23535: Grep Doesn't Support \t as a tab character](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?23535).

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the suggestion. Though I didn't need the -G option for solving my problem, only the escaping sequence (in my case, something like this worked: grep $'\t'$patternPrefix$'\t'morePatternData searchFile ).

Answer (score 2):

The Perl-RegEx understand '[\t]', so you can do like this:

```
echo -e "\t : words" | grep -P '^[\t]'
```

the basic-regexp and extended-regexp need for these a "blank" (RegEx for "Space" / "Tab"):

```
echo -e "\t : words" | grep -G '^[[:blank:]]'
echo -e "\t : words" | grep -E '^[[:blank:]]'
```

maybe you can use it this way:

```
echo -e "\t : words" | grep -E '^[[:blank:]]{2,8}'
echo -e "\t : words" | grep -G '^[[:blank:]]\{2,8\}'
```

Comment: `grep -P` is great (Perl syntax, fast implementation) but unfortunately it is optional and some distributions still don't include it by default.

Comment: this is still experimental option. for example this refuses to use multiline regexp in external file for -f grep option.