# How can I match square bracket in regex with grep?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am trying to match both `[` and `]` with grep, but only succeeded to match `[`. No matter how I try, I can't seem to get it right to match `]`.

Here's a code sample:

```
echo "fdsl[]" | grep -o "[ a-z]\+" #this prints fdsl
echo "fdsl[]" | grep -o "[ \[a-z]\+" #this prints fdsl[
echo "fdsl[]" | grep -o "[ \]a-z]\+" #this prints nothing
echo "fdsl[]" | grep -o "[ \[\]a-z]\+" #this prints nothing
```

Edit: My original regex, on which I need to do this, is this one:

```
echo "fdsl[]" | grep -o "[ \[\]\t\na-zA-Z\/:\.0-9_~\"'+,;*\=()$\!@#&?-]\+" 
#this prints nothing
```

N.B: I have tried all the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928072/whats-the-regular-expression-that-matches-a-square-bracket) post but that didn't work on this particular case. And I need to use those brackets inside `[]`.

Comment: How about `fdsl\[\]` ? Your `]` is unescaped

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the regular expression that matches a square bracket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928072/whats-the-regular-expression-that-matches-a-square-bracket)

Comment: @Joe: Not really a duplicate, since this has to deal with bash's quirks

Comment: @Joe, neither of those solutions worked for me..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [BRE/ERE Bracketed Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) section of POSIX regex specification:

> 1. [...] The right-bracket ( `']'` ) shall lose its special meaning and represent itself in a bracket expression if it occurs first in the list (after an initial circumflex ( `'^'` ), if any). Otherwise, it shall terminate the bracket expression, unless it appears in a collating symbol (such as `"[.].]"` ) or is the ending right-bracket for a collating symbol, equivalence class, or character class. The special characters `'.'`, `'*'`, `'['`, and `'\'` (period, asterisk, left-bracket, and backslash, respectively) shall lose their special meaning within a bracket expression.

and

> 7. [...] If a bracket expression specifies both `'-'` and `']'`, the `']'` shall be placed first (after the `'^'`, if any) and the `'-'` last within the bracket expression.

Therefore, your regex should be:

```
echo "fdsl[]" | grep -Eo "[][ a-z]+"
```

Note the `E` flag, which specifies to use ERE, which supports `+` quantifier. `+` quantifier is not supported in BRE (the default mode).

The solution in Mike Holt's answer `"[][a-z ]\+"` with escaped `+` works because it's run on GNU grep, which [extends the grammar to support `\+` to mean repeat once or more](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html#Basic-vs-Extended). It's actually [undefined behavior according to POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_02) (which means that the implementation can give meaningful behavior and document it, or throw a syntax error, or whatever).

**If you are fine with the assumption that your code can only be run on GNU environment, then it's totally fine to use Mike Holt's answer**. Using `sed` as example, you are stuck with BRE when you use [POSIX `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html) (no flag to switch over to ERE), and it's cumbersome to write even simple regular expression with POSIX BRE, where the only defined quantifier is `*`.

#### Original regex

Note that `grep` consumes the input file line by line, then checks whether the line matches the regex. Therefore, even if you use `P` flag with your original regex, `\n` is always redundant, as the regex can't match across lines.

While it is possible to [match horizontal tab **without** `P` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976715/search-for-tabs-without-p-using-grep), I think it is more natural to use `P` flag for this task.

Given this input:

```
$ echo -e "fds\tl[]kSAJD<>?,./:\";'{}|[]\\!@#$%^&*()_+-=~\`89"
fds     l[]kSAJD<>?,./:";'{}|[]\!@#$%^&*()_+-=~`89
```

The original regex in the question works with little modification (unescape `+` at the end):

```
$ echo -e "fds\tl[]kSAJD<>?,./:\";'{}|[]\\!@#$%^&*()_+-=~\`89" | grep -Po "[ \[\]\t\na-zA-Z\/:\.0-9_~\"'+,;*\=()$\!@#&?-]+"
fds     l[]kSAJD
?,./:";'
[]
!@#$
&*()_+-=~
89
```

Though we can remove `\n` (since it is redundant, as explained above), and a few other unnecessary escapes:

```
$ echo -e "fds\tl[]kSAJD<>?,./:\";'{}|[]\\!@#$%^&*()_+-=~\`89" | grep -Po "[ \[\]\ta-zA-Z/:.0-9_~\"'+,;*=()$\!@#&?-]+"
fds     l[]kSAJD
?,./:";'
[]
!@#$
&*()_+-=~
89
```

Comment: GNU grep equates the usage of `\+` in BRE mode with the usage of `+` in ERE mode, but I agree that it's a better idea to use EREs if they're needed (if for no reason other than portability).

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: Thanks for the hint, I found the GNU documentation about this: http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html#Basic-vs-Extended

Comment: yeah, `\n` is useless here, so for `sed`.

Answer (score 11):

One issue is that `[` is a special character in expression and it cannot get escaped with `\` (at least not in my flavors of grep). Solution is to define it like `[[]`.

Answer (score 3):

According to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

> In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (\), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-). The usual metacharacters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash.

... and ...

> The closing bracket (]), the caret (^) and the hyphen (-) can be included by escaping them with a backslash, or by placing them in a position where they do not take on their special meaning.

So, assuming that the particular flavor of regular expressions syntax supported by `grep` conforms to this, then I would have expected that `"[ a-z[\]]\+"` *should* have worked.

However, my version of grep (GNU grep 2.14) only matches the `"[]"` at the end of `"fdsl[]"` with this regex.

However, I tried using the other technique mentioned in that quote (putting the `]` in a position within the character class where it cannot take on its normal meaning, and it seems to have worked:

```
$ echo "fdsl[]" | grep -o "[][a-z ]\+"
fdsl[]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why `"[][a-z ]\+"` works - it's most likely a non-portable extension, since I can't find anything about it in the specification http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05

Comment: @nhahtdh I'm not sure why you're surprised that this works, since the only differences between this and the regex in your answer (which is, btw, a better answer since it provides a more concrete explanation of *why* this works) are minor. You have the space in a different spot, and instead of using the slash in front of the `+`, you use the `-E` option.

Comment: @MikeHolt It's a valid concern, since by right, the POSIX specs doesn't define behavior for `\+` (as linked in my comment). Actually, it is **undefined behavior** by POSIX specs (section 9.3.2).

Comment: @nhahtdh, can I use `+` in sed ? currently I am using this regex with `sed` and sticking with `\+`

Comment: I agree it's a valid concern. It just seems like using a backslash to enable ERE syntax on an individual character basis is a well-known and widely supported convention. Perhaps my perception of this is skewed though.

Comment: @Jahid Yes. I use `\+` very frequently in `sed`.

Comment: @nhahtdh and Mike Holt, If using `+` and `\+` is disputed, what about `\{1,\}`, this can do the same thing...right..?

Comment: @Jahid: If you are using GNU tools, `\+`, `\{1,\}` and `\?` are supported as extension to BRE. Only `*` is official part of BRE according to POSIX specs.

Comment: @Jahid I wouldn't say `\+` is disputed so much as it is perhaps not as portable, and evidently not POSIX-compliant. If you're using GNU grep on some version of Linux, and you don't care about portability, you're probably safe in using `\+`. The man page states explicitly that a non-metacharacter can be turned into a metacharacter by escaping it with a backslash. So this is not some undocumented feature.

Comment: It should be noted that I don't disagree with anything nhahtdh has said, and in fact I think his answer is a better answer. We were just approaching the problem from different angles. He framed it in a POSIX context, and I happily assumed a GNU/Linux context.