# Grep Tab, Carriage Return, & New Line

Tags: grep

I'm trying to use Grep to find a string with Tabs, Carriage Returns, & New Lines.  Any other method would be helpful also.

```
grep -R "\x0A\x0D\x09<p><b>Site Info</b></p>\x0A\x0D\x09<blockquote>\x0A\x0D\x09\x09<p>\x0A\x0D\x09</blockquote>\x0A\x0D</blockquote>\x0A\x0D<blockquote>\x0A\x0D\x09<p><b>More Site Info</b></p>" *
```

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: I just want to find the files recursively that contain the line between the quotes above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep a tab in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825552/grep-a-tab-in-unix)

Answer (score 3):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825552/grep-a-tab-in-unix)

If using GNU grep, you can use the Perl-style regexp:

```
$ grep -P '\t' *
```

Also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833/how-do-you-search-for-files-containing-dos-line-endings-crlf-with-grep-on-linu)

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to enter a literal Carriage Return character into your grep string. So:

```
grep -IUr --color "^M"
```

will work - if the `^M` there is a literal CR that you input as I suggested.

If you want the list of files, you want to add the `-l` option as well.

Comment: How would I apply this to the string I'm trying to match above between the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686705/7128154) answer:

> Grep is not sufficient for this operation.
>
> [pcregrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pcregrep), which is
> found in most of the modern Linux systems can be used ...

**Bash Example**

```
$ pcregrep -M "try:\n    fro.*\n.*except" file.py
```

returns

```
try:
    from tifffile import imwrite
except (ModuleNotFoundError, ImportError):
```